# Given the following vectors $\vec{u}$ and $\vec{v}$,

Tags: linear-algebra

[image]

I dont really know how to start such a question.
I was thinking about \begin{matrix}
        -1 & -4 & 1 &0&0&0 \\
        0 & 8 &   0&1&0&0 \\
        -2 & 4 &  0&0&1&0  \\
        -3&1&0&0&0&1 \\
        \end{matrix}
but I am not sure. Can someone give me an idea of how to start such a question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For $z$, think of (one of) the simplest linear combinations of $u$ and $v$.

For $w$, you are thinking in the right direction: you can choose it to be an element of the standard basis - just take one and see if it works, otherwise try another.